# Always display a picture even if the link is broken?

Tags: images, validation

What I would like is to have a sort of fall back photo so I don't get red Xs.. Something like "photo unavailable please come back later"

Is there a way to check if the image path is valid and if not display another photo.

(I really only need the "link is valid" bit.. I can figure the rest out)

Comment: @Kendrik - What template tag or other PHP are you using to display the photo?

Comment: Please tell me, did my solution helped you?

Answer (score 1):

There's a PHP function, called [getimagesize()](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php), it can do what you're looking for.

For example:
$url is the image url

```
$imgsize = @getimagesize( $url ); // @ is needed to prevent error messages

if ( $imgsize       // is the variable is not false
 && $imgsize[0] > 0     // and if the img width is larger than 0
     && $imgsize[1] > 0     // and if the img height is larger than 0
   )
{
    // your file exists, write your code here
}
else
{
    // your file is not available, write your code here
}
```

If you specify it more, I can make this look better for example into template.